# Recursive Function To Create Array

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree

i use kohana framework and i am trying to code recursive function to create category tree.

My Categories Table

```
id      int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
name    varchar(50)     NO      NULL     
parent_id   int(11)     NO      NULL     
projects_count  int(11)     NO      NULL
```

My Example Which Is Not Work

```
public static function category_list($parent_id = 0)
{
    $result =  Database::instance()->query('
        SELECT name, projects_count 
        FROM project_categories
        WHERE parent_id = ?', 
        array($parent_id)
    );

    $project_categories = array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $project_categories[] = $row;

        Project_Categories_Model::factory()->category_list($parent_id + 1);
    }

    return $project_categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this kind of hierarchical data implementation is highly non-optimal, because to get every subcategory you need do a separate query to the database. Like here you want to create recursion function.

If you still can change your table architecture please check [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

This article describes a solution, how to fetch the whole hierarchy in one time query, so the recursive function will not be necessary.